# Moving android application to another account

Tags: android, billing

I am planning to move my application to another account.

**Question 1:** Can I do it without closing my old account?

**Question 2:** My application has in-app payments, so according to this [spec](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139626). This article states

> In-app billing: The moment your application is transferred over, the
> billing service will begin signing all billing responses using your
> new keypair. Old versions of your app will     immediately fail to
> authenticate billing responses. To prepare for this, you'll need to
> push     out a version of your app in advance that attempts to
> authenticate requests using both your old and new keypair.

What is authenticating billing responses? Is this something they have in their demo application Security.java class?

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append("....");
String base64EncodedPublicKey = stringBuilder.toString();
PublicKey key = Security.generatePublicKey(base64EncodedPublicKey);
verified = Security.verify(key, signedData, signature);
```

If yes, then what do they mean by

> attempts to authenticate requests

What are the requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A1**. Yes. No need to close old account

**A2**. No need to change anything. Since November '11 keys are connected to apps not to accounts, so feel free to migrate apps as many times as you want.

Tried for myself: all went fine.